# Validation not working Spring Boot, Spring in Action excercise

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am following along with a chapter exercise in Spring in Action the chapter goes through validation but even when I POST the forms with empty input it does not return any form of validation errors! ***No matter what I do I cannot trigger a validation error response, the form is just accepted as it is completely empty.***

Full project @ https://github.com/AdrianLarssonGit/tacoworld/tree/master/tacoworld

Below is what I assume is the relevant code:

**OrderController.java**:

```
package com.tacoworld;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.tacoworld.TacoOrder;

@Slf4j
@Controller
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrderController {

    @GetMapping("/current")
    public String orderForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("tacoOrder", new TacoOrder());
        return "orderForm";
    }
    
    @PostMapping
    public String processOrder(@Valid TacoOrder tacoOrder, Errors errors) {
        if(errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "orderForm";
        }
        else {
            log.info("Order submitted: " + tacoOrder);
            return "redirect:/";
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

**orderForm.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>
Taco Cloud

</title>
<link th:href="@{style.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

<form method="POST" th:action="@{/orders}" th:object="${tacoOrder}">
<h1>Order your taco creation</h1>

<img th:src="@{/images/startSplash.jpg}" />
<br>
<a th:href="@{/design}" id="another">Design another taco!</a><br/>


<h3>Deliver my taco to...</h3>
<label for="deliveryName">Name: </label>
<input type="text" th:field="*{deliveryName}" />
<span class="validationError" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('deliveryName')}" th:errors="*{deliveryName}">TEST Error</span>
<br/>
<label for="deliveryStreet">Street address: </label>
<input type="text" th:field="*{deliveryStreet}"/>
<br/>
<label for="deliveryCity">City: </label>
<input type="text" th:field="*{deliveryCity}"/>
<br/>
<label for="deliveryState">State: </label>
<input type="text" th:field="*{deliveryState}"/>
<br/>
<label for="deliveryZip">Zip code: </label>
<input type="text" th:field="*{deliveryZip}"/>
<br/>
<h3>Here's how I'll pay...</h3>
<label for="ccNumber">Credit Card #: </label>
<input type="text" th:field="*{ccNumber}"/>
<br/>
<label for="ccExpiration">Expiration: </label>
<input type="text" th:field="*{ccExpiration}"/>
<br/>
<label for="ccCVV">CVV: </label>
<input type="text" th:field="*{ccCVV}"/>
<br/>

<input type="submit" value="Submit order" />
</form>
</body>
```

**TacoOrder.java**:

```
package com.tacoworld;

import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.constraints.Digits;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.CreditCardNumber;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import lombok.Data;


@Data
public class TacoOrder {
    @NotBlank(message="Delivery name is required")
    private String deliveryName;
    @NotBlank(message="Name must be at least 5 char long")
    private String deliveryStreet;
    @NotBlank(message="Name must be at least 5 char long")
    private String deliveryCity;
    @NotBlank(message="Name must be at least 5 char long")
    private String deliveryState;
    @NotBlank(message="Name must be at least 5 char long")
    private String deliveryZip;
    @CreditCardNumber(message="Name must be at least 5 char long")
    private String ccNumber;
    @Pattern(regexp="^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])([\\/])([1-9][0-9])$",message="Wrong pattern MM/YY is needed")
    private String ccExpiration;
    @Digits(integer=3, fraction=0,message="Invalid CCV")
    private String ccCVV;
    
    private List<Taco> tacos = new ArrayList<>();

    
    public void addTaco(Taco taco) {
        this.tacos.add(taco);
        }
}
```

I am using Spring Boot so have not done much of POM editing except for trying to solve this particular problem, I attach it here anyway for reference:

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.tacoworld</groupId>
    <artifactId>tacoworld</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>tacoworld</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.12</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
   <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Remove `javax.validation` and `hibernate-validator` both are already pulled in by `spring-boot-starter-validation` and are likely causing issues.Remove `@Validated` from the controller that isn't needed and will / might cause issues as well. The code shown here isn't the same as your repo, the latter is missing a `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency,.

Comment: And your code in the repo does not work. It displays a form without any input fields

Comment: Sorry about the repo! I have now pushed. I also removed the overlapping dependencies in the POM file, removed @Validated, rebuilt project, restarted server and I am still able to click all the way through with empty forms.

Comment: Works as it should. You only have `@NotBlank` which allows `null` values. You need an additional `@NotNull` or use the `@NotEmpty` one.

Comment: That is so strange. I added the NotEmpty along with the NotNull to try to trigger some validation response but I am still able to click all the way through with empty forms, tried multiple browsers, restarting servers, etc. (Also tried all three NotBlank, NotNull, NotEmpty at the same time but still no validation response)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the whole POM, shutting down Eclipse then regenerate the POM through Spring Boot seems to have solved the problem.

Do not know if it was the POM or Eclipse who acted up but now it does indeed work.

Comment: I have seen issues with Eclipse like this. I personally very much prefer IntelliJ.